# Best way to display a Images and Doc files from base64-string - Android and Blackberry

Tags: android, base64, blackberry-10, inappbrowser

I am trying to display image,docs from base64-string for Android and IOS. I am using inapp browser plugin to display image and doc files in app.

For IOS i am able to display images using below code.But facing issue with Android and Blackberry.

```
window.open(urlData, "_blank", "location=no,enableviewportscale=yes");
```

I am passing urlData parameter as base-64 string. Android and Blackberry nothing is displaying. After searching i found this post.

> Alternative: just store that whole data string in your database. Then when you render your tag you can simply dump it into the src
>   attribute:>" />

After inserting above code i am able to display image but how to close the image ? How to open image in popup ? So user can close the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, window.open probably isn't working because all URLs have to be granted access specifically, for security. You can try to bypass it with this in your config.xml -- I don't know if it will work for data: URLs.

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<preference name="WebSecurity" value="disable"/>
```

If this doesn't work, how to show an image in a pop-up comes down to the design of your app.  If you're using something like Ionic Framework, Bootstrap, jQueryUI, or Ratchet, they each have components for Modals or Dialogs you could potentially use. If you're not using a UI framework, you'll have to design your own pop-up div to contain the image tag, that is hidden again when you tap or dismiss it. Finding information on Google about how to do this is not very hard.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this issue in BlackBerry using below steps.

1)Remove webWorks.js from index.html

2)Replace below script inside index.html

```
<script src="worklight/cordova.js"></script> to <script src="../../cordova.js"></script>
```

3) Add below code inside js file. Need to pass urlData as Base64 string and filename.

```
requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 7 * 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
    localPath = fs.root.toURL() + fileName;
    ft.download(urlData, localPath, function (entry) {
    entry.file(function (file) { console.log(file.size); });
    window.open(localPath, "_blank", "location=yes,closebuttoncaption=Close,enableViewportScale=yes");
}, function (e) { console.log('download error'); console.log(e); });
});
```